# I am trying to scrap website but get only one array detail in xml file

Tags: php, arrays, xml, web-scraping, goutte

I am trying to scrape [this](https://www.simplyhired.com/search?q=pharmacy%20technician&l=American%20Canyon%2C%20CA&job=X5clbvspTaqzIHlgOPNXJARu8o4ejpaOtgTprLm2CpPuoeOFjioGdQ) webpage. In this webpage I have to get the job title and its location. Which I am able to get from my code. But the problem is coming that when I am sending it in XML, then only one detail is going from the array list.

I am using goutte CSS selector library and also please tell me how to scrap pagination in goutte CSS selector library.

here is my code:

```
$httpClient = new \Goutte\Client();
$response = $httpClient->request('GET', 'https://www.simplyhired.com/search?q=pharmacy+technician&l=American+Canyon%2C+CA&job=X5clbvspTaqzIHlgOPNXJARu8o4ejpaOtgTprLm2CpPuoeOFjioGdQ');



$job_posting_location = [];
$response->filter('.LeftPane article .SerpJob-jobCard.card .jobposting-subtitle span.JobPosting-labelWithIcon.jobposting-location span.jobposting-location')
->each(function ($node) use (&$job_posting_location) {
$job_posting_location[] = $node->text() . PHP_EOL;
});

$joblocation = 0;
$response->filter('.LeftPane article .SerpJob-jobCard.card .jobposting-title-container h3 a')
->each( function ($node) use ($job_posting_location, &$joblocation, $httpClient) {
$job_title = $node->text() . PHP_EOL; //job title
$job_posting_location = $job_posting_location[$joblocation]; //job posting location

// display the result
$items = "{$job_title} @ {$job_posting_location}\n\n";
global $results;
$result = explode('@', $items);
$results['job_title'] = $result[0];
$results['job_posting_location'] = $result[1];

$joblocation++;

});

function convertToXML($results, &$xml_user_info){
    foreach($results as $key => $value){
       if(is_array($value)){
           $subnode = $xml_user_info->addChild($key);
           foreach ($value as $k=>$v) {
               $xml_user_info->addChild("$k",htmlspecialchars("$v"));
           }
       }else{
           $xml_user_info->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
       }
       }
   return $xml_user_info->asXML();
}

$xml_user_info = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
$xml_content = convertToXML($results,$xml_user_info);

$xmlFile = 'details.xml';
$handle = fopen($xmlFile, 'w') or die('Unable to open the file: '.$xmlFile);

if(fwrite($handle, $xml_content)) {
    echo 'Successfully written to an XML file.';
}
else{
    echo 'Error in file generating'; 
}
```

what i got in xml file --

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><job_title>Pharmacy Technician
 </job_title><job_posting_location> Vallejo, CA
 </job_posting_location></root>
```

what i want in xml file --

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<job_title>Pharmacy Technician</job_title>
<job_posting_location> Vallejo, CA</job_posting_location>
<job_title>Pharmacy Technician 1</job_title>
<job_posting_location> Vallejo, CA</job_posting_location>
<job_title>Pharmacy Technician New</job_title>
<job_posting_location> Vallejo, CA</job_posting_location> 
and so on...
</root>
```

Comment: We can't see the source data you're trying to parse. We also don't know what output you were expecting. Please provide full details of the scenario

Comment: Also I think you mean "scrape" not "scrap". They have two different meanings :-). You can [edit] your question when you are ready with more information. Thanks.

Comment: sorry @ADyson, i have edited the question please help me.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But, again, please provide (a sample of) the source HTML you're trying to parse. Don't expect us to go and get it ourselves from the website. Also it's better to see what your PHP is downloading exactly, rather than what is returned in the browser - we don't know (without spending time on detailed debugging) if that's been added to by JS, AJAX, iframes etc etc) so it might be different than what your PHP sees. You also still haven't given an example of the expected result either. All we have an example of is the result you _don't_ want.

Comment: Also you didn't make it clear but we can assume you're using this library: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte ?

Comment: yes you are right @ADyson.
again i edited the question

Comment: my friend @ADyson what i am trying to do is, I got result in array. right but when i convert array to xml i got only one result not total list of array

Comment: To be perfectly clear, _the results of the scraping work_, ie. the result array has all the data you expect, however you have a problem converting it to XML?

Comment: Well we still can't see the content that array or the HTML it was derived from, so we can't tell whether the code is processing it correctly or not. We don't know if the problem is the raw data or what you're doing with it, and we have no way of executing or debugging the code either, without something to feed into it. I think we need to see the output of `var_export($response);`.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the values in the `$results` variable. You're would need to do something like this to append:

```php
$results[] = [
  'job_title' => $result[0];
  'job_posting_location' => $result[1]
];
```

However here is no need to put the data into an array at all, just create the
XML directly with DOM.

Both your selectors share the same start. Iterate the card and then fetch
related data.

```
$httpClient = new \Goutte\Client();
$response = $httpClient->request('GET', $url);

$document = new DOMDocument();
// append document element node
$postings = $document->appendChild($document->createElement('jobs'));

// iterate job posting cards
$response->filter('.LeftPane article .SerpJob-jobCard.card')->each(
    function($jobCard) use ($document, $postings) {
        // fetch data
        $location = $jobCard
          ->filter(
              '.jobposting-subtitle span.JobPosting-labelWithIcon.jobposting-location span.jobposting-location'
          )
          ->text();
        $title = $jobCard->filter('.jobposting-title-container h3 a')->text();
        // append 'job' node to group data in result
        $job = $postings->appendChild($document->createElement('job'));
        // append data nodes
        $job->appendChild($document->createElement('job_title'))->textContent = $title;
        $job->appendChild($document->createElement('job_posting_location'))->textContent = $location;
    }
);

echo $document->saveXML();
```